# How to set the default resolution in windows 8.1 winjs app

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, winjs

I'm working on my first winjs app for windows 8.1. So I'm a newbie in this topic, so please forgive me if I ask something obvious.

My problem is the resolution of the target machine (DELL Latitude E7440 with touch screen) is 1920x1080, but when I run the app, it runs in 1370x771. Which is a bit confusing for me.

So my question is, how can I tell the app to run in the same resolution as the OS runs.

Strange thing I discovered: If I set the  "Change the size of apps text, and other items on the screen (...)" settings from larger to default in the display settings then suddenly my app runs in the desired full hd resolution. But I don't wanna depend on this setting.

I know I could use ViewBox control, but all of the graphics and everything is designed for full hd resolution, so ViewBox would simply scale it down, this solution sounds a bit ridiculous considering I have a full hd laptop, and full hd design as well...

This app is only for this particular machine, so I don't have to deal with different resolutions.

Any tip/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows abstracts the physical device resolution specifically so you don't have to think about scaling issues. Just do your work against the resolution that's reported from the API. This is done because a high pixel density display can result in UI that's too small to be usable, e.g. touch targets that get too small for fingers. Most of the time, then, a 1920x1080 display that's on a smaller physical device (e.g. 13" or smaller screens) gets a 140% scaling factor applied, hence it reports something closer to 1366x768.

Generally speaking, then, if you write responsive CSS for layout then you really don't need to worry about scaling at all with the exception of providing raster graphics that can work at the 100%, 140%, and 180% scaling plateaus (and 240% on Windows Phone 8.1).

For more details refer to my free ebook from Microsoft Press, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), which you can also read (free) within the [Microsoft Press Guided Tour app](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/bccb3097-0491-48b1-9b7f-46e5c7e8bcac) in the Store. Page 42 (Chapter 1) has a short overview on Views and Resolution Scaling; the Branding Your App section on page 113 talks about sizes of logo/splashscreen images for different resolutions, and then Chapter 8, "Layout and Views" (starting on page 421) goes into all the details, especially "Screen Resolution, Pixel Density, and Scaling" on page 437.